# Where can I find the "storage_account_name","storage_account_key","storage_container_name" in azure?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

**I found the following code needs "storage_account_name","storage_account_key","storage_container_name" .**

```
def invokeBatchExecutionService():
    storage_account_name = "mystorageacct" # Replace this with your Azure Storage Account name
    storage_account_key = "a_storage_account_key" # Replace this with your Azure Storage Key
    storage_container_name = "mycontainer" # Replace this with your Azure Storage Container name
    connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + storage_account_name + ";AccountKey=" + storage_account_key
    api_key = "abc123" # Replace this with the API key for the web service
    url = "https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/e810bf8e16bb4dec9719b07f0205b0bb/services/bc8304cebe1a42bfb2518b302eba979d/jobs"
    uploadFileToBlob("input1data.file_extension", # Replace this with the location of your input file, and valid file extension (usually .csv)
        "input1datablob.file_extension", # Replace this with the name you would like to use for your Azure blob; this needs to have the same extension as the input file
        storage_container_name, storage_account_name, storage_account_key)
```

**I can find "api_key" here:
[image]
But where can I find "storage_account_name","storage_account_key","storage_container_name" ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Azure Storage account:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/

First, you create one:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-quickstart-create-account
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-create-storage-account

During this quickstart, you choose the account name. Azure gives you a key to access it:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-create-storage-account#manage-your-storage-access-keys

Then, you need to create a Blob Container inside this Storage account. You choose the name as well. Use the portal or the CLI to do so:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-azure-cli#create-a-container

Note that you can create keys at the container level, or at the storage level, depending of your needs.

Comment: Sir,this registration is required to bind the visa card, but I do not have this visa card. Does this mean that it is not free for "storage_account_name","storage_account_key","storage_container_name"?

Comment: Yes, having a storage account is not free. It seems your code is uploading to a Storage container, so either your client/customer own one (and pay for it) and give you credentials, either you have to pay to get one.